# RegEx for different bracket pairs

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx for next strings:

```
caption
"caption"
<caption>
[caption]
(caption)
etc
```

In this context caption is [a-zA-Z]. I can use backreferences for same symbols like `"`, but what I shoud do with pair symbols like `()`, `[]`, `<>`, etc. ?

Comment: If you wait just a few more decades for Perl6 to get released... http://www.perl6.org/archive/rfc/145.html ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done if your regex engine supports conditionals:

```
(?:(")|(<)|(\[)|(\())[A-Za-z]*(?(1)")(?(2)>)(?(3)\])(?(4)\))
```

Not that that is more readable than the solutions proposed by @stema or @Anirudh :)

**Explanation:**

```
(?:       # Match either...
 (")      # a quote, capture it in group 1
|         # or
 (<)      # an opening angle bracket --> group 2
|         # or
 (\[)     # an opening bracket --> group 3
|         # or
 (\()     # on opening parenthesis --> group 4
)         # End of alternation
[A-Za-z]* # Match any ASCII letters
(?(1)")   # If group 1 matched before, then match a quote
(?(2)>)   # If group 2 matched before, then match a closing angle bracket
(?(3)\])  # If group 3 matched before, then match a closing bracket
(?(4)\))  # If group 4 matched before, then match a closing parenthesis
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify it explicitly..

```
\[[a-zA-Z]+\]|\<[a-zA-Z]+\>|"[a-zA-Z]+"|\([a-zA-Z]+\)
```

Answer (score 2):

A pattern has no chance to know, which two different characters belong together. You have to list those cases in an alternation:

```
(["'])[a-zA-Z]*\1|<[a-zA-Z]*>|\[[a-zA-Z]]*\]|\([a-zA-Z)]*\)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3511e)

Comment: Some regex flavors do have the chance to know this. But I prefer your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can't be done except with many |

```
<[a-zA-z]+>|\[[a-zA-z]+\]|\([a-zA-z]+\)
```

or risking having more false positive

```
[<\[\(][a-zA-z]+[>\]\)]
```

if you need this for replace, many programming languages support a callback function

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string. For example: